# How to compare two noderefs in alfresco javascript

Tags: javascript, alfresco

I am have two noderefs in alfresco javascript file which i am trying to compare as below.

```
if(personRef == userAsscNodeRef){
    do something
}else{
    do something else
}
```

It seems to be syntactically correct but always going to else part. I tried with strict equal i.e. === as well as  adding .toString() to both noderefs but still same result.

How can it be possible?

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is repo tier Javascript, you are really dealing with Java `NodeRef` objects and `==` behaves like it does in Java and compares identity. You want to compare equivalence, so use `personRef.equals(userAssocNodeRef)`. Yes, pretty unexpected behavior. Beware of Strings and Date objects as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String()`:

```
if(String(personRef) == String(userAsscNodeRef)){
    do something
}else{
    do something else
}
```